# Volume keys stopped working

Tags: media, keys

Recently had a power outage in my area and my desktop was rebooted. Running Ubuntu 22.04. When the system came back up the volume keys that I configured (F2 - Volume down; F3 - Volume up; F4 - Volume mute) stopped working. If I run mate-volume-control I can see the output volume and I can control it with my mouse. The volume goes up and down and I can mute it. However, if I use the volume keys, a dialog box comes up showing the volume going up or down and or muting, but the actual volume does not change nor does it mute. Looking at mate-volume-control the output volume also does not change nor does the mute toggle activate.

I think I saw this a few times before and in the past, a reboot would fix it. But not now. Volume keys still don't work. I tried resetting them in Keyboard Shortcuts in the Control Center and even reassigning them to other keys to no avail. It acts like it's working but the actual volume doesn't change.

Help! I use these volume keys all the time! The work around of having to run mate-volume-control (or pavucontrol) just to adjust the volume is a real PITA.

Comment: Not a solution but I can go into pavucontrol and change the configuration for my audio control to something else then back and this resets it but this shouldn't happen in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Working with System76, they pointed me to https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/#other-useful-commands, which solved my problem.